# adjusting label to slider value swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a slider and label in my swift project. On the storyboard, I control dragged my slider onto my controller class for that page and created an outlet and also an action. I control dragged another label as an outlet. I am trying to update the label based on the slider's value. I don't know where i am going wrong.

Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderVal: UILabel!

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    println("Slider changing to \(currentValue) ?")
    sliderVal.text = "\(currentValue) Km"
}
```

I can see in the log the sliderValueChanged funciton is being called and the log is printing the value but the label's text is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

I just put a slider object and label on my login screen and used the same methodology and code to change the label text and it worked but it will not work inside my tab bar controller. Does this shed any light on what the issue may be?

Comment: Is sliderVal correctly linked up as IBOutlet? Also, I assume you're calling this from the user changing the slider value and not from a background process?

Comment: @Chackle By correctly linked up, what exactly do you mean? I control dragged the sliderVal label to my controller class and selected the outlet option. It is being called when the user changes the value

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I'll take a look and try and replicate the issue myself here. Hopefully I can help

Comment: slider returns decimal values between 0 and 1 for example 0.623457, parsing this to integer `Int(sender.value)` will either return 0 or 1

Answer (score 21):

Update the slider value in Main queue

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    println("Slider changing to \(currentValue) ?")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(){
        sliderVal.text = "\(currentValue) Km"
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var currentValue = Int(slider.value)
println("Slider changing to \(currentValue) ?")
startTime.text = "\(currentValue) Km"
```

Comment: same result. Value is changing in log but not on the label

Comment: maybe check in a project that has a tab bar controller. The tab also has a navigation controller. Should there be anything in my custom tab bar class apart from the standard: class HomeController: UIViewController {

Comment: sorry I'm not sure what you mean? Which demo? A swift demo with a tab bar controller which has a slider in one tab?

Comment: OK so I just put a slider object and label on my login screen and used the same methodology and code to change the label text and it worked but it will not work inside my tab bar controller. Does this shed any light on what the issue may be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79652/discussion-between-user2363025-and-memon).

Answer (score 3):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var slideroutlet: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var lblValue: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {

    lblValue.text = String(slideroutlet.value)
    imgView.alpha = CGFloat(slideroutlet.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3: 
Select .allEvents for its UIControlEvents.

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.updateKmsLabel(sender:)), for: .allEvents)
// To use
func updateKmsLabel(sender: UISlider!) {
    let value = Int(sender.value)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.kmsLabel.text = "\(value)"
        print("Slider value = \(value)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to just print the value the slider is at:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
            print(sender.value)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, this is one way.

```
var slider: UISlider()
var label: UILabel()

func numberValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    slider.setValue(Float(Int(slider.value)), animated: true)
    updateLabels(slider.value)
}
fun updateLabels(nV: Float?) {
    if let v = nV {
        self.label.text = "\(v)"
    }
}

slider.addTarget (self,
                 action: #selector(numberValueChanged)
                 forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it seemed to have worked:

```
// For the slider
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

// For the label displaying the slider value
@IBOutlet weak var sliderVal: UILabel!

// For the "submit" button action
@IBAction func newSliderValue(_ sender: Any) {
    sliderVal.text = String(slider.value)
}
```

Note, I used a button to submit my new slider value, not what you did.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used on the latest Xcode 12.5 and IOS 14:

```
@IBAction func sliderValue(_ sender: Any) {
    label.text = "\(slider.value)"
}
```

In the code above, we’re simply getting the value of the slider and adding it to a string.

Then we’re assigning that string as the text of the label.