# change Value in a TextField with Sliders based on a calculated Value [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextfield, uislider

I am creating some simple Input/Output stuffs.
I have a function which calculates something and returns the value in a textfield. I want to change the value in the textfield with a slider based on this calculated value. Let's say my function returns the value 4,76 and my maximum value of the slider should be value*2 (= 9,52) and the minimum value is 0. My problem is I don't really know how I should create a slider which changes a value, where the value is not hardcoded.

```
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    sender.value = Float(calculateWaterAmount())!
    sender.minimumValue = 0
    sender.maximumValue = sender.value*2

    waterAmountTextField.text = String(sender.value)
}
```

The function `calculateWaterAmount()` returns a Double value. The slider should be able to change the value of this function and return it into a textField.

EDIT: 
so basically it should look like this [slider with value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTjU1.png). 
the value which will be displayed in the textfield depends on the formula in the function calculateWaterAmount() and each time i call the function with different values it should obviously return different values and the slider should may change the displayed value, if needed, to, lets say, a value between 0 and n*2, where n = calculated value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adjusting label to slider value swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639675/adjusting-label-to-slider-value-swift)

Comment: isn't `sender.value = xx` cause value change event again? You better use `open func setValue(_ value: Float, animated: Bool) // move slider at fixed velocity (i.e. duration depends on distance). does not send action` instead.

Comment: @Ryan No, setting the value does not call any change event.

Comment: @Ryan hey thank you for your answer, but that does not seem to be what i am looking for. i have updated my question, so its better to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
slider.maximumValue = Float(calculateWaterAmount()) * 2.0
```

every time water amount changed. With this you'll always have maximumValue equals the doubled value of the func